# Program Doesnt intercept SIGQUIT specifically?

Tags: c, signals, tty, stty

this program seems to not being able to intercept **SIGQUIT** signal Althought it can intercept **SIGINT**

```
void sig(int sig){
    printf("Got signal(%d)", sig);
}
int main(){
    signal(SIGQUIT, sig);
    char x[10];     fgets(x, 10, stdin);
}
```

I am running ubuntu 20 and running `stty -a` command gives first line output
which i guess mean SIGQUIT is correctly mapped to **^D** but pressing it seems to do nothing .I also tryied with **^\** since i am confused between `quit=^\` and `eof=^D` as **stty** says so if someone can clear this misunderstanding between both two.

```
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
```

Comment: Why do you think the label `eof` in the output of stty is related to SIGQUIT?

Comment: I read an article saying SIGQUIT is mapped to ctrl-d so I tryied Both ctrl-d and ctrl-\. This is the article https://www.networkworld.com/article/2702471/unix---sending-signals-to-processes.html

Comment: That article is incorrect.  By default,  ^d does not send SIGQUIT.  Rather than confusing the issue with how the terminal is handling keystrokes, just use `kill` to send SIGQUIT via `kill -QUIT $pid`

Comment: Maybe this will help clarify: https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~saul/parasite/man/man4/tty.4.html#:~:text=or%20EOF%2C%20character.-,EOF,and%20the%20EOF%20is%20discarded.

Comment: @williamPursell Tryied it Nothing still also note that it's not just doesnt call signal handler it also caused program to not exit, like nothing happened

Comment: Of course nothing seemed to happen.  First, `printf` is not safe to call in a signal handler.  But more likely `fgets` is simply not returning when the signal is received.  Since stdout is line buffered and your message does not include a newline, nothing is printed and the  program is still blocked on a read.  For starters, just try adding a newline to the message you print.